# When a linear map on exterior power is induced

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, exterior-algebra

Let $k$ be a field, $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space. If $A: V \to V$ is a linear map, it induces a linear map $\wedge^k(A): \wedge^k(V) \to \wedge^k(V)$. Suppose $B: \wedge^k(V) \to \wedge^k(V)$ is any linear map. What are conditions on $B$ that are equivalent to the existence of $A$ such that $B=\wedge^k(A)$?

Notice that the map $A \to \wedge^k(A)$ is polynomial, so we have a polynomial map of affine spaces $\phi: \mathbb{A}^{n^2} \to \mathbb{A}^N$, where $N ={n \choose k}^2$. From the point of view of algebraic geometry I'm asking to find a set of generators of the ideal $I_X$ of the subvariety $X=\phi(\mathbb{A}^{n^2}) \subset \mathbb{A}^N$.

Comment: Probably easier to start with the full exterior algebra, since the indiced algebra homomorphisms are exactly those $S : \Lambda(V) \rightarrow \Lambda(V)$ with $S|_V \subset V$.

Comment: Maybe this paper by Bruns and Conca is of interest to you, they study the (closure of the) image of the exterior power map: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.3399.pdf

Comment: @Alex did you figure out the answer? I came up to the same question.... I was hoping you will have a clue!

Comment: @user350168 Sorry, no progress.